# How to compile a program to work on a 64 bit machine

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, windows-server-2008

I have a 32 bit application compiled on a Windows 2003 32 bit machine.

When I try to install it on Windows server 2008 or Windows 7, I get an error saying "Unable to start application 0xc0000142"

And, I am using Visual Studio 2008, and I tried setting the configruation ot x64, x86 and mixed platforms, but still not getting any success.

please let me know if I am missingo ut anything obvious or if more information is needed.

And it works on a Server 2003 64 bit without problem.

Comment: Um... 32-bit programs will work on 64-bit... So that can't be the (only) reason.

Comment: Have you installed the correct version of the Visual C++ runtime libraries on the target machine?

Comment: The DllMain() function of one of the DLLs used by the program is returning FALSE.  You'll need a debugger.

Comment: Does it run on Server 2003 under a non-administrator account?  You're probably violating the principle of least privilege, and UAC is catching you (on Vista, 7, Win2k8, Win2k8R2)

Comment: I Installed the latest version of vc++ redistributables on it, but still get the error. @BenVoigt: I will try to see if it runs when UAC is disabled.

Comment: @roymustang86: It needs the redist version that came with your compiler, not the latest.  VC2010 redist will not help a VC2008 app, even VC2008 vs VC2008SP1 can cause failures.  All these redist packages can be installed side-by-side.

Comment: Check the event log. Information about missing dependencies (probably the runtime libraries) can turn up there.

Comment: Nothing pops up on the Event viewer, and @BenVoigt, I installed the vc_reditx86 that came with the setup program.

Comment: Try running [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) in trace mode - that'll show you exactly what is failing to load.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Yeah, I just did that, so I was linking vss_uid.lib, psapi.lib and traffic.lib, all windows api libraries, and when compiled, it was packaging psapi.dll, vss.dll and traffic.dll into the program directory. On deleting those files, the program works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was linking vss_uid.lib, psapi.lib and traffic.lib, all windows api libraries, and when compiled, it was packaging psapi.dll, vss.dll and traffic.dll into the program directory. On deleting those files, the program works perfectly now.